# Is [] parameter in the AngularJS module definition compulsory?

Tags: angularjs

In definition of AngularJS module, `[]` is a parameter for other depended module on this module.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
</script>
```

**My Question is,**
**Is this parameter `[]` necessary,** because the the following link or example they didn't mentioned `[]` parameter, but in above example(w3schooles), if we remove '[]' parameter then code will not give correct output [see it](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_module)?

Please see the this link [openstack](https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/stable/kilo/openstack_dashboard/static/dashboard/launch-instance/launch-instance.model.js#L15), they are not using `[]` parameter

```
var module = angular.module('hz.dashboard.launch-instance');
/**
* @ngdoc service
* @name launchInstanceModel
*
* @description
* This is the M part in MVC design pattern for launch instance
* wizard workflow. It is responsible for providing data to the
* view of each step in launch instance workflow and collecting
* user's input from view for creation of new instance. It is
* also the center point of communication between launch instance
* UI and services API.
*/
module.factory('launchInstanceModel', ['$q',
'cinderAPI',
'glanceAPI',
'keystoneAPI',
'neutronAPI',
'novaAPI',
'novaExtensions',
'securityGroup',
'serviceCatalog',
function ($q,
cinderAPI,
glanceAPI,
keystoneAPI,
neutronAPI,
novaAPI,
novaExtensions,
securityGroup,
serviceCatalog) {
var initPromise,
allNamespacesPromise;
// Constants (const in ES6)
var NON_BOOTABLE_IMAGE_TYPES = ['aki', 'ari'],
SOURCE_TYPE_IMAGE = 'image',
SOURCE_TYPE_SNAPSHOT = 'snapshot',
SOURCE_TYPE_VOLUME = 'volume',
SOURCE_TYPE_VOLUME_SNAPSHOT = 'volume_snapshot';
/**
* @ngdoc model api object
*/
var model = {
initializing: false,
initialized: false,
/**
* @name newInstanceSpec
*
* @description
* A dictionary like object containing specification collected from user's
* input. Its required properties include:
*
* @property {String} name: The new server name.
* @property {String} source_type: The type of source
* Valid options: (image | snapshot | volume | volume_snapshot)
* @property {String} source_id: The ID of the image / volume to use.
* @property {String} flavor_id: The ID of the flavor to use.
*
* Other parameters are accepted as per the underlying novaclient:
* - https://github.com/openstack/python-novaclient/blob/master/novaclient/v2/servers.py#L417
* But may be required additional values as per nova:
* - https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/master/openstack_dashboard/api/rest/nova.py#L127
*
* The JS code only needs to set the values below as they are made.
* The createInstance function will map them appropriately.
*/
// see initializeNewInstanceSpec
newInstanceSpec: {},
/**
* cloud service properties, they should be READ-ONLY to all UI controllers
*/
availabilityZones: [],
flavors: [],
allowedBootSources: [],
images: [],
allowCreateVolumeFromImage: false,
arePortProfilesSupported: false,
imageSnapshots: [],
keypairs: [],
metadataDefs: {
flavor: null,
image: null,
volume: null
},
networks: [],
neutronEnabled: false,
novaLimits: {},
profiles: [],
securityGroups: [],
volumeBootable: false,
volumes: [],
volumeSnapshots: [],
/**
* api methods for UI controllers
*/
initialize: initialize,
createInstance: createInstance
};
// Local function.
function initializeNewInstanceSpec(){
model.newInstanceSpec = {
availability_zone: null,
admin_pass: null,
config_drive: false,
user_data: '', // REQUIRED Server Key. Null allowed.
disk_config: 'AUTO',
flavor: null, // REQUIRED
instance_count: 1,
key_pair: [], // REQUIRED Server Key
name: null, // REQUIRED
networks: [],
profile: {},
security_groups: [], // REQUIRED Server Key. May be empty.
source_type: null, // REQUIRED for JS logic (image | snapshot | volume | volume_snapshot)
source: [],
vol_create: false, // REQUIRED for JS logic
vol_device_name: 'vda', // May be null
vol_delete_on_terminate: false,
vol_size: 1
};
}
/**
* @ngdoc method
* @name launchInstanceModel.initialize
* @returns {promise}
*
* @description
* Send request to get all data to initialize the model.
*/
function initialize(deep) {
var deferred, promise;
// Each time opening launch instance wizard, we need to do this, or
// we can call the whole methods `reset` instead of `initialize`.
initializeNewInstanceSpec();
if (model.initializing) {
promise = initPromise;
} else if (model.initialized && !deep) {
deferred = $q.defer();
promise = deferred.promise;
deferred.resolve();
} else {
model.initializing = true;
model.allowedBootSources.length = 0;
promise = $q.all([
getImages(),
novaAPI.getAvailabilityZones().then(onGetAvailabilityZones, noop),
novaAPI.getFlavors(true, true).then(onGetFlavors, noop),
novaAPI.getKeypairs().then(onGetKeypairs, noop),
novaAPI.getLimits().then(onGetNovaLimits, noop),
securityGroup.query().then(onGetSecurityGroups, noop),
serviceCatalog.ifTypeEnabled('network').then(getNetworks, noop),
serviceCatalog.ifTypeEnabled('volume').then(getVolumes, noop)
]);
promise.then(
function() {
model.initializing = false;
model.initialized = true;
// This provides supplemental data non-critical to launching
// an instance. Therefore we load it only if the critical data
// all loads successfully.
getMetadataDefinitions();
},
function () {
model.initializing = false;
model.initialized = false;
}
);
}
return promise;
}
/**
* @ngdoc method
* @name launchInstanceModel.createInstance
* @returns {promise}
*
* @description
* Send request for creating server.
*/
function createInstance() {
var finalSpec = angular.copy(model.newInstanceSpec);
cleanNullProperties();
setFinalSpecBootsource(finalSpec);
setFinalSpecFlavor(finalSpec);
setFinalSpecNetworks(finalSpec);
setFinalSpecKeyPairs(finalSpec);
setFinalSpecSecurityGroups(finalSpec);
return novaAPI.createServer(finalSpec);
}
function cleanNullProperties(finalSpec){
// Initially clean fields that don't have any value.
for (var key in finalSpec) {
if (finalSpec.hasOwnProperty(key) && finalSpec[key] === null) {
delete finalSpec[key];
}
}
}
//
// Local
//
function onGetAvailabilityZones(data) {
model.availabilityZones.length = 0;
push.apply(model.availabilityZones, data.data.items
.filter(function (zone) {
return zone.zoneState && zone.zoneState.available;
})
.map(function (zone) {
return zone.zoneName;
})
);
if(model.availabilityZones.length > 0) {
model.newInstanceSpec.availability_zone = model.availabilityZones[0];
}
}
// Flavors
function onGetFlavors(data) {
model.flavors.length = 0;
push.apply(model.flavors, data.data.items);
}
function setFinalSpecFlavor(finalSpec) {
if ( finalSpec.flavor ) {
finalSpec.flavor_id = finalSpec.flavor.id;
} else {
delete finalSpec.flavor_id;
}
delete finalSpec.flavor;
}
// Keypairs
function onGetKeypairs(data) {
angular.extend(
model.keypairs,
data.data.items.map(function (e) {
e.keypair.id = e.keypair.name;
return e.keypair;
}));
}
function setFinalSpecKeyPairs(finalSpec) {
// Nova only wants the key name. It is a required field, even if None.
if(!finalSpec.key_name && finalSpec.key_pair.length === 1){
finalSpec.key_name = finalSpec.key_pair[0].name;
} else if (!finalSpec.key_name) {
finalSpec.key_name = null;
}
delete finalSpec.key_pair;
}
// Security Groups
function onGetSecurityGroups(data) {
model.securityGroups.length = 0;
push.apply(model.securityGroups, data.data.items);
// set initial default
if (model.newInstanceSpec.security_groups.length === 0 &&
model.securityGroups.length > 0) {
model.securityGroups.forEach(function (securityGroup) {
if (securityGroup.name === 'default') {
model.newInstanceSpec.security_groups.push(securityGroup);
}
});
}
}
function setFinalSpecSecurityGroups(finalSpec) {
// pull out the ids from the security groups objects
var security_group_ids = [];
finalSpec.security_groups.forEach(function(securityGroup){
if(model.neutronEnabled) {
security_group_ids.push(securityGroup.id);
} else {
security_group_ids.push(securityGroup.name);
}
});
finalSpec.security_groups = security_group_ids;
}
// Networks
function getNetworks() {
return neutronAPI.getNetworks().then(onGetNetworks, noop);
}
function onGetNetworks(data) {
model.neutronEnabled = true;
model.networks.length = 0;
push.apply(model.networks, data.data.items);
}
function setFinalSpecNetworks(finalSpec) {
finalSpec.nics = [];
finalSpec.networks.forEach(function (network) {
finalSpec.nics.push(
{
"net-id": network.id,
"v4-fixed-ip": ""
});
});
delete finalSpec.networks;
}
// Boot Source
function getImages(){
return glanceAPI.getImages({status:'active'}).then(onGetImages);
}
function isBootableImageType(image){
// This is a blacklist of images that can not be booted.
// If the image container type is in the blacklist
// The evaluation will result in a 0 or greater index.
return NON_BOOTABLE_IMAGE_TYPES.indexOf(image.container_format) < 0;
}
function onGetImages(data) {
model.images.length = 0;
push.apply(model.images, data.data.items.filter(function (image) {
return isBootableImageType(image) &&
(!image.properties || image.properties.image_type !== 'snapshot');
}));
addAllowedBootSource(model.images, SOURCE_TYPE_IMAGE, gettext('Image'));
model.imageSnapshots.length = 0;
push.apply(model.imageSnapshots,data.data.items.filter(function (image) {
return isBootableImageType(image) &&
(image.properties && image.properties.image_type === 'snapshot');
}));
addAllowedBootSource(model.imageSnapshots, SOURCE_TYPE_SNAPSHOT, gettext('Instance Snapshot'));
}
function getVolumes(){
var volumePromises = [];
// Need to check if Volume service is enabled before getting volumes
model.volumeBootable = true;
addAllowedBootSource(model.volumes, SOURCE_TYPE_VOLUME, gettext('Volume'));
addAllowedBootSource(model.volumeSnapshots, SOURCE_TYPE_VOLUME_SNAPSHOT, gettext('Volume Snapshot'));
volumePromises.push(cinderAPI.getVolumes({ status: 'available', bootable: 1 }).then(onGetVolumes));
volumePromises.push(cinderAPI.getVolumeSnapshots({ status: 'available' }).then(onGetVolumeSnapshots));
// Can only boot image to volume if the Nova extension is enabled.
novaExtensions.ifNameEnabled('BlockDeviceMappingV2Boot')
.then(function(){ model.allowCreateVolumeFromImage = true; });
return $q.all(volumePromises);
}
function onGetVolumes(data) {
model.volumes.length = 0;
push.apply(model.volumes, data.data.items);
}
function onGetVolumeSnapshots(data) {
model.volumeSnapshots.length = 0;
push.apply(model.volumeSnapshots, data.data.items);
}
function addAllowedBootSource(rawTypes, type, label) {
if (rawTypes && rawTypes.length > 0) {
model.allowedBootSources.push({
type: type,
label: label
});
}
}
function setFinalSpecBootsource(finalSpec) {
finalSpec.source_id = finalSpec.source && finalSpec.source[0] && finalSpec.source[0].id;
delete finalSpec.source;
switch (finalSpec.source_type.type) {
case SOURCE_TYPE_IMAGE:
setFinalSpecBootImageToVolume(finalSpec);
break;
case SOURCE_TYPE_SNAPSHOT:
break;
case SOURCE_TYPE_VOLUME:
setFinalSpecBootFromVolumeDevice(finalSpec, 'vol');
break;
case SOURCE_TYPE_VOLUME_SNAPSHOT:
setFinalSpecBootFromVolumeDevice(finalSpec, 'snap');
break;
default:
// error condition
console.log("Unknown source type: " + finalSpec.source_type);
}
// The following are all fields gathered into simple fields by
// steps so that the view can simply bind to simple model attributes
// that are then transformed a single time to Nova's expectation
// at launch time.
delete finalSpec.source_type;
delete finalSpec.vol_create;
delete finalSpec.vol_device_name;
delete finalSpec.vol_delete_on_terminate;
delete finalSpec.vol_size;
}
function setFinalSpecBootImageToVolume(finalSpec){
if(finalSpec.vol_create) {
// Specify null to get Autoselection (not empty string)
var device_name = finalSpec.vol_device_name ? finalSpec.vol_device_name : null;
finalSpec.block_device_mapping_v2 = [];
finalSpec.block_device_mapping_v2.push(
{
'device_name': device_name,
'source_type': SOURCE_TYPE_IMAGE,
'destination_type': SOURCE_TYPE_VOLUME,
'delete_on_termination': finalSpec.vol_delete_on_terminate ? 1 : 0,
'uuid': finalSpec.source_id,
'boot_index': '0',
'volume_size': finalSpec.vol_size
}
);
}
}
function setFinalSpecBootFromVolumeDevice(finalSpec, sourceType) {
finalSpec.block_device_mapping = {};
finalSpec.block_device_mapping[finalSpec.vol_device_name] = [
finalSpec.source_id,
':',
sourceType,
'::',
(finalSpec.vol_delete_on_terminate ? 1 : 0)
].join('');
// Source ID must be empty for API
finalSpec.source_id = '';
}
// Nova Limits
function onGetNovaLimits(data) {
angular.extend(model.novaLimits, data.data);
}
// Metadata Definitions
/**
* Metadata definitions provide supplemental information in detail
* rows and should not slow down any of the other load processes.
* All code should be written to treat metadata definitions as
* optional, because they are never guaranteed to exist.
*/
function getMetadataDefinitions() {
// Metadata definitions often apply to multiple
// resource types. It is optimal to make a single
// request for all desired resource types.
var resourceTypes = {
flavor: 'OS::Nova::Flavor',
image: 'OS::Glance::Image',
volume: 'OS::Cinder::Volumes'
};
angular.forEach(resourceTypes, function (resourceType, key) {
glanceAPI.getNamespaces({
'resource_type': resourceType
}, true)
.then(function (data) {
var namespaces = data.data.items;
// This will ensure that the metaDefs model object remains
// unchanged until metadefs are fully loaded. Otherwise,
// partial results are loaded and can result in some odd
// display behavior.
if(namespaces.length) {
model.metadataDefs[key] = namespaces;
}
});
});
}
return model;
}
]);
})();

    Status
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array or `[]` parameter is needed to specify dependent modules when you *declare* your own module, so this should only happen once per module.

The second notation, without the parameter is just retrieving the module so you can attach controllers/services/filters/... to it.

Use the array notation for the *declaration* of your module, use the single parameter notation if you want to *add* something to it.

For example:

in app.module.js

```
    //You want to make use of the ngRoute module, 
    //so you have to specify a dependency on it
    angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

You will only specify the dependencies on your module once, when you declare it.

in main.controller.js

```
//You want to add a controller to your module, so you want to retrieve your module
angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl);

function mainCtrl() { };
```

Now angular will try to find a module by that name instead of creating one, when it doesn't find one, you'll get some errors, which explains your original question.
You will typically do this every time you want to add something to your module.

Note that you could also achieve this by storing your module in a global variable when you create it and then access the module by that variable when you want to add things to it, however as you probably know, creating global variables is a bad practice.

Comment: thanks, I am  getting  something but if you give example or tutorials, then it would be better to understand..

Comment: @ NexusDuck, thank I get the given example but how they are using in this https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/stable/kilo/openstack_dashboard/static/dashboard/launch-instance/launch-instance.model.js#L15 (please see the highlighted.

Comment: That's just one file where they add a factory (if you look more down you'll see module.factory) to it, if you look at https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/stable/kilo/openstack_dashboard/static/dashboard/launch-instance/launch-instance.js, you'll see that they declare their module there with a dependency on ngSanitize

Comment: ngSanitize is just another module supplied by the angularjs team, it's just a module like ngRoute or our own modules but for sanitizing html code. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize

Comment: Thanks for nice explaination, "The Warlock" has given the same definition thanks both of you, If you find this question have any sense, plz up vote..

Answer (score 1):

Facing an error with angular is a bliss because it provides the link to description of the error in the console.

From an example [page](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=MyApp) like that...

> When defining a module with no module dependencies, the array of dependencies should be defined and empty.

`var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);`

> To retrieve a reference to the same module for further configuration, call angular.module without the array argument.

`var myApp = angular.module('myApp');`

Comment: Thanks for reply, your answer sounds me, could you see once again question I updated with source code or this link and explain how they are using  https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/stable/kilo/openstack_dashboard/static/dashboard/launch-instance/launch-instance.model.js#L15

Comment: because if you go here - https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/stable/kilo/openstack_dashboard/static/dashboard/launch-instance/launch-instance.js#L4 - you will see they have `defined` it before they use it in model. Here they use the dependency array.